# Is it possible with PostgresSQL JDBC to force usage of client only Prepared Statements?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I would like to eliminate Server Side Prepared Statements on PGSQL without changing my code. Is this something possible on JDBC with some parameter?

To be clear, I would like to use Client Prepared Statements, meaning my code will not change, and I will enjoy the security benefits of Prepared Statements, but not compile it on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/server-prepare.html) says:

> There might be cases when you would want to disable use of server-prepared statements. For instance, if you route connections through a balancer that is incompatible with server-prepared statements, you have little choice.
>
> You can disable usage of server side prepared statements by setting `prepareThreshold=0`

A code sample:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ...");
// get the PostgreSQL-specific class
org.postgresql.PGStatement pgstmt = pstmt.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGStatement.class);
// disable server-side prepared statements
pgstmt.setPrepareThreshold(0);
```

If you `unwrap` the `org.postgresql.PGConnection` in your `java.sql.Connection`, you can also set the threshold on the connection level for all prepared statements on that connection.

Example for adding it to the URL: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true&prepareThreshold=0`

Comment: Looks good! Will it work on the connection string? Or only on the PreparedStatement object?

Comment: Actually this does not compile. The PreparedStatement object does not have the setPrepareThreshold method :-(

Comment: I fixed the omission and added something to cover setting on the connection level.

Comment: Yes, because you need to cast your Connection, not PreparedStatement, as in the following:

     (org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn.setPrepareThreshold(0);

Works without objection in Eclipse.